# Rostest and C++: Test node does not exist or is not executable

Tags: ros, c++, shell, ros-kinetic, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to integrate my workspace with GitLab CI and have been encountering this issue in the CI shell:

`FAILURE: Test node [husky_test/common_spawn_test] does not exist or is not executable`

However, locally, everything works fine and the test yields a success. Here's the testing section of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
#############
## Testing ##
#############

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_rostest_gtest(common_test test/common.test src/common.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(common_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

And the gitlab-ci.yaml file contains the following lines for running the tests:

```
- catkin build --summarize --no-status --force-color
- catkin run_tests --no-status --force-color
```

Maybe I have to add the file as an executable in the CMakeLists, but I'm not sure. Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346903/rostest-and-c++:-test-node-does-not-exist-or-is-not-executable/) by [gerhmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41972/gerhmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on 2020-03-18**:
Any luck with this?

**Comment by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) on 2020-03-18**:
What was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the answer was just a simple mistake. I'll mark this as solved. Thanks for the help!

---

Originally posted by [gerhmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41972/gerhmi/) with karma: 5 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2021-01-05**:
please detail what the simple mistake was. If you made it then others may.